# Free versus schematic variables in lemmas

Tags: isabelle, theorem-proving

What is the difference between these three lemmas (in their meaning, in possible usage)?

```
  consts d::int
  consts e::int

  lemma  L1:"⟦2 dvd d; 2 dvd e⟧ ⟹ 2 dvd (d+e)" by simp

(* lemma L1: even d ⟹ even e ⟹ even (d + e) *)

  lemma  L2:"⋀(f::int) (g::int). ⟦2 dvd f; 2 dvd g⟧ ⟹ 2 dvd (f+g)" by simp

(* lemma L2: even ?f ⟹ even ?g ⟹ even (?f + ?g) *)

  lemma  L3:"⟦2 dvd (h::int); 2 dvd (i::int)⟧ ⟹ 2 dvd (h+i)" by simp

(* lemma L3: even ?h ⟹ even ?i ⟹ even (?h + ?i) *)
```

Comment: There are no free variables in the first lemma, `e` and `d` are the constants you declared above the lemma.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: Thanks. I have changed my question. (I am a newbie and rather confused). The question still holds. What is the difference between these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables names are different, but they're logically the same. The difference comes into play if you instantiate the schematic variables, in which case you have to use the names provided in the theorem. It's why they tell us to use proof techniques which don't depend on names of variables. If the names change in the distribution proofs, it will break our proofs.

See the emails titled ***universal quantifiers vs. schematic variables***, ***strange error message***, and ***x is a special variable***, in this months emails on the Isabelle user's list:

- [lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2015-October/thread.html](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2015-October/thread.html)

Free variables are implicitly universally quantified by the meta-all operator, a lesson demonstrated by C.Sternagel some time ago. You explicitly quantify `f` and `g` of `L2`, where `h` and `i` are implicitly quantified in `L3`.

In the 2012-10 threads, see emails titled ***Free variables deadhorse beat...*** and ***Happy New Year with Free/Bound Variables*** in the following:

- [lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2012-October/thread.html](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2012-October/thread.html)
- [lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2012-December/date.html](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2012-December/date.html)
- [lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2013-January/thread.html](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2013-January/thread.html)

Comment: It might be useful to directly link the beginning of the mentioned threads, like https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2015-October/msg00014.html

Comment: @Gergely, I didn't count them, but there's like 15-30 separate pages for the 5 thread topics that I mentioned. I guess I'm linking the way I prefer to work. I like to get my bearings with a tree, or with an overview for the month. Clicking links, and not knowing where it's all going doesn't work good for me. But, you can add more links if you want to.

Comment: Thank you J. Dudechensky for your answer. I am unfortunately not at the level of knowledge to understand it yet, not to mention the referenced threads. So I leave this answer unaccepted, and that is not a criticism of your answer, it is a fact of it is not (yet) answering my question on a level I can understand (and that is the definition of an accepted answer here, otherwise I could have as well used Google.) Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: @TFuto, simple things can be hard; it happens to me frequently, but there's nothing much to be said. That's why the question sat there for about a day. You show the output of the two formulas. They're identical except for the identifiers. It's like two C functions, `int add(int x, int y) {return x + y}` vs. `int add(int h, int k) {return h + k}`. You don't need to thank me. You're too picky about an answer's form over content. If I answer a question, I have to think, and I get something from it. If I let it sit there until someone more knowledgeable answers it, I usually get more.